# Is "receive" natural in this context?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

I was a big bully in school, and I haven't seen any of them since then, so I'm just a little nervous about how they're going to receive me.

Is "receive" natural in this context? Is it formal?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a natural usage of **receive**. First of all, **receive** is too formal in the context of the rest of the language. But I think the main problem is that **receive** is usually used for guests or visitors, and it means 'greet' or 'welcome'. I don't think you will be welcoming them. In your sentence, I think it would be more natural to say:

> I'm just a little nervous about how they're going to **react to meeting** me.

I think **react** is better because it introduces an element of unpredictability - you don't know what will happen when you meet them.

Comment: I would not go with ***react to meeting*** if I am a bully.. Instead more daily usage of a word ***greet*** comes in place such as **I'm just a little nervous about how they're going to *greet* me.** so the line can go along with **either with a punch or a bully at my size**

Comment: I disagree. 'Greet' usually implies good will or at least courtesy and there is no reason to expect that someone who was bullied will feel like greeting their bully. If I dislike someone, I don't greet them. I ignore them. If I had been bullied, I might even angrily confront the person who had bullied me. That's why I suggested 'react' instead of 'greet'. Your phrase 'greet with a punch' is possible but it is an ironic use of the word 'greet', not a standard use.

Comment: He is a bully person not a person bullied by others and expecting a group of bullies to accept him into their group so greet actually fits.

Comment: Yes I know he is the bully. He is worried that the people he bullied will still be angry at him. Maybe they will greet him in a friendly way but maybe they will confront him and cause a scene. He simply doesn't know what will happen and he is concerned. There is no reason to expect they will 'greet' him. That's why I prefer 'react to'.